# Normalizing by column: the data.table way

Tags: r, data.table

Starting with a simple datatable

```
ID MAX X1 X2 X3 X4
E0 9   2  1  2  3
E0 21  9  0  10 2
```

I would like to normalize all columns from `X1` to `X4` dividing by `MAX`.

The unelegant, data.frame way would be

```
dt$X1 <- dt$X1/dt$MAX
```

What is the elegant data table way?

I tried with `dt[, .SD/MAX, by = ID]`, but this also reduces MAX to 1.

Comment: I think `dt[, .SD/MAX, by = .(ID, MAX)]` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `data.table v1.9.7`, we can also specify the columns in `.SDcols`, loop through the columns (`lapply(.SD, ...`), divide by the 'MAX' and assign (`:=`) the output back to the columns of interest.

```
dt[, paste0("X", 1:4) := lapply(.SD, `/`, MAX), .SDcols= X1:X4]
dt
#   ID MAX        X1        X2        X3        X4
#1: E0   9 0.2222222 0.1111111 0.2222222 0.3333333
#2: E0  21 0.4285714 0.0000000 0.4761905 0.0952381
```

Comment: The important bit is `.SDcols` and you could also omit `lapply()` here: `dt[,X1:X4 := .SD / MAX, .SDcols = X1:X4]`